# uploading .net web services/WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, deployment

I've created a small web service using VS2010/C#, how should I upload it to my remote host?

I have wsdl, asmx, WCF Web service file, and some other files, what should I upload?

- Should I change these files before upload?
- I see something like `localhost:xxxxx` in these files, should I change them to remote host domain name before uploading?
- In which folders should I upload my files?

Comment: Why do you have both a .asmx and a "WCF Web service file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to right click on the web site or web application project in Visual Studio, select publish, and publish it locally. Then copy all those file to the server.